# Apply a color tint to a specific color in an image using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a lightbulb image, which the glass bulb is pure white (#ffffff) and the cap is gray (#757575). Is  there a way to change my image from:

[image]

to: (the #ffffff color will become #f3e73c)

[image]

using javascript only (or probably, jQuery)?

(sorry, still can't post pictures, all I can give is the links)

Comment: So you you're asking for code? sure?

Comment: This can be done with CSS too. :)

Comment: @Justcode code or a plugin for jquery, or any idea on how I can achieve something like that. 'cause I've searched for color tints that can be applied images, but what they do is like a filter to the whole image and not to a specific color only.

Comment: Have you tried using SVG + CSS, and just changing the class of your bulb with JS? (Your chances of getting an answer here will be much bigger, btw, if you show what you already tried!)

Comment: why cant you try by replace the yellow image when Hover(concentrate on positioning).. it shows like when hover the bulb become yellow..

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl how? btw, the black background of the bulb represents the background of the parent div.

Comment: @leo, sorry but i haven't tried svg yet as I am not yet knowledgeable when it comes to svg. :(

Comment: @Sarath, because my aim was to change the #ffffff color of the bulb to other colors, such as yellow, green, purple, etc while trying to animate them. will it be a better solution if I create multiple images with these colors? :)

Comment: @user3686003 check out my new http://jsfiddle.net/ea77vbLf/1/ :) it's awesome :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go: CSS approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/ea77vbLf/

```
.bulb{
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkEGo.png);
}
.bulb:hover{
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPrTk.png);    
}
```

CHECK THIS OUT! CSS WITH JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY CHANGES COLOR EVERY 3 SECS!

http://jsfiddle.net/ea77vbLf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the white part of the image transparent instead of white, then place it in a DIV of the same size, and change the background colour of the div

Comment: the black background of the image represents the background of a div.

Comment: so just change the background colour of the parent div.

Comment: but the background color of the div and the bulb should be different.

Comment: So put a new div in. One that is exactly the same size of the image (i.e. completely invisible)